# Display an attachment in a Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, attachment

I want to display an image, which is in an attachment in a customized object, in lightning component.
I make a query like that in the server side controller :

```
@AuraEnabled
public static Attachment getImage(Id parentId){
    if(!Schema.sObjectType.sObject__c.isAccessible()){
        throw new System.NoAccessException();
        return null;
    }

    return [select Id, Name, ContentType from Attachment 
            where parentid=:parentId and ContentType in ('image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif')];
}
```

Here is the component :

```
<aura:component controller="Controller"  implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
<aura:attribute name="oct" type="sObject__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="actId" type="Id"/>
<aura:attribute name="imageSrc" type="String" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<aura:iteration var="a" items="{!v.act}">
    <div>{!a.Name} : {!a.Description__c}</div>
    <img src="{!v.imageSrc}" /> 
    <br/>
</aura:iteration>
```

and the part of the client side controller :

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

    var actionImage = component.get("c.getImage");
    actionImage.setParams({
        parentId : component.get("v.actId")
    });

    actionImage.setCallback(this, function(rep){
        var attachment = rep.getReturnValue();
        component.set("v.imageSrc", "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + attachment.Id);
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(actionImage);
}
```

})

So I got an error for this line, I guess : `component.set("v.imageSrc", "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + "attachment.Id");`
because of the Id. And if I put a "true" Id I see the image, but I don't see how I can retrieve the good Id dynamically...

Answer (score 1):

You can remove double quotes as attachment is JavaScript variable and the correct syntax is:

```
component.set("v.imageSrc", "/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=" + attachment.Id);
```

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot to correct it in my question, but even without the quotes it doesn't work...

Comment: Console.log the return object ..that will help you log response variable

Comment: if i put console.log(attachment) it says that it's null... How can I set a value in it ?

Comment: This means your server is returning null.put system.debug and debug apex code..

Comment: In the component I can't use the system.debug (it says it is not defined) and I suspect that my error is in the component... Since the attachement is null, when I put `var attachment = rep.getReturnValue();` it doesn't work ? How can I take the value of the attachment ?

Comment: I am asking you to put debug in apex code

Comment: Ok I did it, but I can't see the log, when I filter the log in the console with debug only nothing appear....

Comment: Put debugs after each line of code to see whats going on ..

Comment: Shouldn't it be "...servlet.FileDownload...", instead of "...servlet.File download..."?